# Change localadmin on workstations

Tags: windows-xp

We have scanned our domain and there are just a couple of PC's where an user is localadmin (this was enabled in the past for a certain application/installation). We need to disable this now. Is there a way to do this remotely?

OS: windows XP clients in network / domain environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Active Directory Users and Computers, select the computers in question, right click, select manage, and remove their domain accounts from the Administrators group. Close, and have the users log out and log back in again.

Problem solved.

Comment: thank you, this solution worked for us (actually I did think about this before, but I thought it would not work and I did not test it )  :)  thanks !

Comment: ADUC is a fantastic tool that allows you to do SO MUCH more than just resetting passwords.  I once had a boss that didn't know about the Manage function built into ADUC, and was BLOWN AWAY by the fact that I had device manager open on a remote machine through ADUC.

And you're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the use of restricted groups through group policies. 
I found this article which explains the use of restricted groups in detail:
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Using-Restricted-Groups.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could try psexec \\machinename net localgroup "administrators" "domain\user" /delete